# IMAP is taking too long to load mails | Laravel IMAP

Tags: php, laravel, email, imap

I'm using [Weblex/laravel-imap](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap) to load all my mails from Gmail.

But it takes really a lot of time to load the mails when I go to mywebsite.com/api/mails.
It took 12 seconds for loading only 5 mails.

This is my config/imap.php

```php
'accounts' => [

 'gmail' => [
           'host' => 'imap.gmail.com',
           'port' => 993,
           'encryption' => 'ssl',
           'validate_cert' => true,
           'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
           'password' => 'passwd',
     ],
..
],
..
.
```

This is the controller:

```php
    ## web.php -> Route::get('/api/mails', 'Controller@imap');

    use Webklex\IMAP\Facades\Client;
    use Response;

    public function imap(){
      $mail = Client::account('gmail');
      $mail->connect();
      // dd($mail->getFolders());
      $f = $mail->getFolder('INBOX');
      $messages = $f->query()->since(now()->subDays(1))->get(); // today

      $body = $subject = $date = $from = []; 

      foreach ($messages as $msg) {
        array_push($body, $msg->getHTMLBody(true));
        array_push($subject, $msg->getSubject(true));
        array_push($date, $msg->getDate(true));
        array_push($from, $msg->getFrom(true));
      }

      return Response::json([
        'body' => $body,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'date' => $date,
        'from' => $from
      ]);
    }
```

How do I speed it up?

Comment: Does it have a multi-fetch method?  You seem to be getting each message one at a time, and also getting everything separately.  Also, just making a connection to the server and logging in while will take several seconds on many servers.  The search can take a long time on a big mailbox.  This is why most clients locally cache.

Comment: Couldn't find it in [documentations](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap#advanced-fetching) but it had options to fetch mails without flags and attachments which decreases load time but it didn't really affect but a few seconds on load time (2-3 secs).

Comment: Those examples show doing a get() on the entire result query, not one at a time; that would probably help at the expensive of memory use.

Comment: Do you know any other laravel package that does what you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, my specialty is the IMAP protocol and imaplib and low level access. Again, it takes several seconds just to log into the server and select the folder.

Comment: Thanks for your time mate.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: @Bimal I stored mails within a database as Max has mentioned.
And also created a `button` to check if there are incoming mails.

Comment: @uhbc Okay. I had a query. How do you check if incoming email is not similar to your existing email in database ?